# How to subtract from a number contained in a string?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a string that contains a number, eg,

> images/cerberus5

The desired result

> images/cerberus4

How can I subtract 1 from the '5' in the first string to obtain the '4' in the second?

Comment: @MightyPork Who are you to judge whether or not this person is able to figure out what was already said in a Google search result?  Sure, this question could be more clear including what was tried and what wasn't, but someone brand new to writing code might not understand substring.  Sometimes only a small push is needed to get them into the right direction.

Comment: Can you just answer and or leave? what a noob user. i ask cause i don't know. so why stackoverflow is? for chat hobby? post a day activies? so funny you are.

Comment: @jarwobangun No need for the name calling.

Comment: Well either way you are supposed to show a code you tried, and you didn't do that.

Comment: manipulate where? Server or client? Question is tagged javascript and php

Comment: @jarwobangun I edited your question to make it a bit clearer what you're asking. Feel free to roll it back if I got it wrong.

Comment: @charlietf Server and Client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a raw example, but you could do something like this:

```
$old_var = 'images/cerberus4';
$matches = [];
$success = preg_match_all('/^([^\d]+)(\d+)$/', $old_var, $matches);
$new_val = '';

if (isset($matches[2]) && $success) {
    $new_val = $matches[2][0].((int)$matches[2][0] + 1);
}
```

It's not meant to be the perfect solution, but just to give a direction of a possible option.

What the RegEx doesn't detect (because it's more strict) is that it won't work without a trailing number (like `images/cerberus`), but as it seems an 'expected' pattern I also wouldn't allow the RegEx to be more loose.

By putting this code into a function or class-method you could add a parameter to automatically be able to tell the code to add, subtract or do other modifications to the trailing number.

Comment: ok, i will try to look the code first. the value that i manipulaze is come from input value. i'll check javacript.

Comment: You'll still need back-end validation too. Front-end validation is never enough to make it safe for data-retrieval and database-insertion.

Comment: @jarwobangun The word is 'manipulate', there is no such word as 'manipilaze', although I think there should be :)

Comment: @Allendar yeah, but its a manipulaze switch from input value 1 to value 2. if all process on server-side. it makes the server work hard. so make it as posibble on client-side. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addOne(string){
    //- Get first digit and then store it as a variable
    var num = string.match(/\d+/)[0];
    //- Return the string after removing the digits and append the incremented ones on the end
    return (string.replace(/\d+/g,'')) + (++num);
}

function subOne(string){
    var num = string.match(/\d+/)[0];
    //- Same here just decrementing it
    return (string.replace(/\d+/g,'')) + (--num);
}
```

Don't know if this is good enough but this is just two functions that return the string. If this has to be done via JavaScript so doing:

```
var test = addOne("images/cerberus5");
```

Will return images/cerberus6

and

```
var test = subOne("images/cerberus5");
```

Will return images/cerberus4

Comment: Your code seems good, but be aware that if you match `\d+` in the full string you have to be absolutely sure that it's only there in the end and nowhere else. It might give very strange results in the end. If you know part of the (or the full) structure of the string you should always make the RegEx as strict as possible, to not let it be fooled by unexpected inputs.

Comment: i don't know its work or not. i try document.write(test); it doesn't return anything

Comment: Could you show me your code in the form of a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Allendar what other way would you suggest? using `\d+/$` (If that is valid RegEx but I hope you get what I mean)

Comment: Yes that is valid. You would force the regex only to match if it happens on the end of a line (for end-of-string use `\Z`).